# Pessimistically locking code between processes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-webjobs

We have the following processes that can modify the same dataset:

- Web site (Asp.NET Web API that modifies some parent/child dataset)
- Azure Web Job (C# cod that modifies the same parent/child dataset)

What are the recommended ways to ensure that we keep data integrity when the Parent/Child datasets are modified by the two processes simultaneously (C# Lock statement won't work because it's code running in different processes).

Currently they are using Entity Framework, and the process will load the dataset in memory, work on the data, and then save it.  The problem is that the data may change by the other process A after it is initially read by process B.

The data is in a SQL Azure database.

Can I create a blocking transaction on the parent table record (Id = XXXX) and so other processes just have to wait until the lock is released.  How best to do that?

Otherwise, perhaps some other ideas off the top of my head might be setting a "Locked" field on the parent record, or checking the MAX RowVersion for the parent UNION with each child table (for the Parent ID) and check this RowVersion before and after each change?

Comment: You have to use optimistic concurrency and be prepared that you won't be able to update the data due to changes by a different process. Note that you have to do that even if you use a "lock". Note that EF uses transactions when saving changes. Also, note that trying to "lock" can introduce bottlenecks/starvation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) stored procedure seems to be exactly what you need.

It is very useful when you want to synchronize processes that need to get exclusive access to a part of the database.

This should be something like below. Where `ctx` is a `DbContext` and each of the processes you want to synchronize is using the same shared logical name string "MYLOCKNAME", or anything you want.

```
using (var tran = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        const string lockName = "MYLOCKNAME";

        var resourceParam = new SqlParameter("Resource", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255) { Value = lockName };
        var lockModeParam = new SqlParameter("LockMode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32) { Value = "Transaction" };
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource, @LockMode", resourceParam, lockModeParam);

        // Do stuff with ctx
        // ...

        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        tran.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting stored procedure.  Just curious if you could please provide an example of how to use it with Entity Framework?  For example, var record = DbContext.TableName.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123);  record.ColumnName = "Fred";  DbContext.SaveChanges();   I'm assuming we would want to somehow link the sp_getapplock call with the same transaction as that used implicitly with the entity framework savechanges?   The logic in our c# reads and modifies data from EF models (but want to pessimistically lock these during this time).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  I will play around with that. Will be interesting to see how it performs, creates bottlenecks etc.  I'm assuming that when one process calls sp_getapplock, it will wait until another process has released it.  If we want to lock records at the parent level, can you see any harm in creating unique locknames based on the parent id, for example:  var lockname = "TableName_" + parentRecord.Id.ToString();